# What is the use of groups and payload in custom Annotation In Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Here's My code ,
I tried reading many stuff online but was not able to understand actual use of

```
Class<?> [] groups() default{};
Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
```

Here is my code in which i have used it.

```
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueValidator.class)
public @interface UniqueValue {
    String message() default "Unique Constraint Violated";
    
    Class<?> [] groups() default{};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

### Groups allow you to restrict the set of constraints applied during validation.

In the following example, the `AClass` class has the `bool` attribute that belongs to the `AGroup` group. But when the group of an attribute is not specified, which is the case of the other attributes of `AClass`, then it belongs to the default group `javax.validation.groups.Default`.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;
import javax.validation.constraints.Min;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;

public class AClass {

    @NotBlank
    private String string;

    @Min(2)
    private int integer;

    @AssertTrue(groups = AGroup.class)
    private boolean bool;

    public AClass(String string, int integer, boolean bool) {
        this.string = string;
        this.integer = integer;
        this.bool = bool;
    }
}
```

A group declaration can be a simple empty interface.

```
public interface AGroup { }
```

In the following program, the `validate` method validates all attributes that belong to the default group. But to validate attributes of other groups, you must specify in the `validate` method which group of attributes will be validated.

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;
import org.junit.Assert;

public class Program {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

        // create a AClass and check that everything is ok with it.
        AClass a = new AClass("Foo", 2, false);
        Set<ConstraintViolation<AClass>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(a);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, constraintViolations.size());

        // but has it passed the bool field?
        constraintViolations = validator.validate(a, AGroup.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
        Assert.assertEquals("must be true", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage()
        );
    }
}
```

Source: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/ch05.html#example-driver

### Payloads can be used by clients of the Bean Validation API to assign custom payload objects to a constraint. This attribute is not used by the API itself.

In the following example, the `TestBean` class has an attribute with `Payload`.

```
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class TestBean {

    @NotNull(payload = {ErrorEmailSender.class})
    private String str;

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }

    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }
}
```

Implementation of `ErrorEmailSender` Payload:

```
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Payload;

public class ErrorEmailSender implements Payload {

    public void onError(ConstraintViolation violation) {
        System.out.println("Sending email to support team: "
                + violation.getPropertyPath() + " "
                + violation.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The `Client` program checks whether a `TestBean` instance is valid, and if not, it calls the `Payload` of invalid attributes.

```
import java.util.Set;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolation;
import javax.validation.Validation;
import javax.validation.Validator;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

        TestBean bean = new TestBean();
        Set<ConstraintViolation<TestBean>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(bean);

        if (constraintViolations.size() > 0) {
            constraintViolations.stream().forEach(Client::processError);
        } else {
            //proceed using user object
            System.out.println(bean);
        }
    }

    private static void processError(ConstraintViolation<TestBean> violation) {
        violation.getConstraintDescriptor().getPayload().forEach(p -> {
            if (ErrorEmailSender.class.isAssignableFrom(p)) {
                try {
                    ((ErrorEmailSender) p.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()).onError(violation);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    System.out.println(ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You should see in the output:

```
Sending email to support team: str must not be null
```

Sources:

- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/ch06.html
- https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/java-ee-tutorial/bean-validation/constraint-payload.html